# Winter bash hat issue in mobile profile page

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2015

I noticed that my Winter bash hat, which is hovering over my profile picture on the profile site, has the following issue:

When scrolling down on the page, the hat scrolls with you as if it had a 'position: absolute' on it. This is weird I think it's worth fixing.

Does anyone else see this behavior?